# Twig block calling with parameters

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am kinda new to Symfony and Twig. I am trying to override default Twig form template in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig (Symfony 3.2.6)

As far as I know, block can be defined and then used in other part of template

```
{% block fooBlock %}
// the block body
{% endblock %}
```

When parameters are to be passed into, a macro should be rather used

```
{% macro barMarco(param1, param2, param3) %}
// macro body using param1, param2, param3 etc,
{% endmacro %}
```

In mentioned above file i found something like. this 
The definition of block:

```
{%- block form_errors -%}
    {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
    <ul>
        {%- for error in errors -%}
            <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
        {%- endfor -%}
    </ul>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_errors -%}
```

And usage:

```
{%- block form_row -%}
    <div>
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        {{- form_widget(form) -}}
    </div>
{%- endblock form_row -%}
```

And here's the question: why this block it called with param `(form)`. I thought a macro should be invoked like this?

Comment: `form` is just a variable that lives in the global `context` of `twig`?

Comment: No, it's a form passed from controller and invoked in view e.g. like this {{ form(form) }}

Comment: Yes in that case the `Twig_Function` `form` is called and the variable `form` is passed towards it. See [more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html) here

Comment: So what, in mentioned file there is block definition, and somewhere else must be a macro definition with the same name that probably uses this block definition?

Comment: Well yes, but its a `Twig_Function`, not a macro. If you wanted to call and repeat a block you would've used `{{ block('form_errors') }}`

Comment: Ok, now i think i got this.

Comment: When you want to override . You should 1st extends template, next using {% block name_of_block %} parent() {% endblock %}